# Extjs stange effect after call SlideOut

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, slide

When I call slideOUT the div height reduce to zero and all component scroll up !
How to conserve the Div height.
the goal is slideOut a picture and just after slideIn another picture.
But briefly I have a strange effect between slideIn and slideOut.
because the div height is reduce to zero

```
 Ext.get("MENUNAV_nouvelle_commande").slideOut('r', {
     easing: 'easeOut',
     duration: 1000,
     remove: false,
     useDisplay: false
 });

Ext.get("MENUNAV_nouvelle_commande").slideIn('l', {
     easing: 'easeIn',
     duration: 1000
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what effect you're seeing, but I'm assuming that you mean that when you use slideIn() and slideOut() that all other HTML elements are being moved/repositioned to make room for the new element.  That makes sense, and an easy way around that is to set the style of the sliding element to position:absolute.

If you want to make the element retain its position relative to other elements on the screen, you can place it in a parent element that is positioned relatively.

```
<div style="position:absolute;" id="MENUNAV_nouvelle_commande"></div>

<script>
Ext.core.DomHelper.applyStyles(Ext.get("#MENUNAV_nouvelle_commande"), {
    top:  (window.innerHeight / 2) + 'px',
    left: '0'
});

Ext.get('#MENUNAV_nouvelle_commande).slideIn('t', { options });
</script>
```

Hope that helps.